# How to select champion before automatch?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've read some guides on a champion and want to try it out. However, in automatch the champion may be selected by other players in my team, thus it may not be available to me. How can I select my champion beforehand so that I only matched with games where I can be that champion definitely?

EDIT: If this is impossible, then how can I be sure that my mastery build matches the type of hero I'm playing? For example, I may have a mage build in mastery, but then I may have to play a melee fighter because mages were picked by others.

Comment: If you were allowed to do this, other people would as well.  Then you'd be in the same boat.

Comment: Get a faster computer, the faster the computer the faster you are able to lock in ;)

Comment: Might need to update the answers here as Teambuilder has been around for quite a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blind Pick, the first player to choose a champion gets it.  Your only options are to talk to the player and ask if you can play that champion instead, or to get a faster computer that gets you to Champion Select faster. :)

You can also have better luck if you focus on a less popular champion that not many other folks play.

As far as your masteries and runes go, you can typically build multiple general-purpose rune and mastery pages.  For instance, some possible general rune pages:

- Ability Power, Magic Penetration, Health - good for most AP champions
- Attack Damage, Armor, Magic Resist, Health - good for most AD champions

Some general mastery pages:

- 21/9/0 with all the Attack Damage stuff in the Offense tree (good for most melee & ranged AD champs)
- 21/9/0 with all the Ability Power stuff in the Offense tree (good for most AP champs)
- 9/21/0 (good for most champions you might want to be "tanky")
- 0/9/21 (good for most support champions)

You can then switch to whatever general page works best for the champion you got, even if you didn't get the one you hoped for.

These won't be as perfect as mastery/rune pages that are tuned exactly for a champion, but if you're working on learning a champion they'll be pretty good.  Until you get really experienced with a champion it's unlikely that the tiny edge you're getting from a precisely tuned mastery/rune page will outweigh your personal skill level anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't in Blind Pick it's first come first serve.

It's basically the same in Draft Pick except that only one or two are picking at a time.

Comment: then how can i match my mastery build to the type of hero I'm playing?

Comment: @bizso09 Either you set up several mastery build for for the champions you can play, one for tanking one for ranged ad carry one for ap carry one for support and such. Or you can just set it up in those 60+ seconds you have available during champion select, like most other does.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't. You can try and ask politely in the chat if someone who picked "your" champion would be so kind to let you play it, but thats about it. If you play Draft Mode you can ask it while people are banning (making the chance to get it somewhat higher if the people are nice).

Alternativly, you can play custom games against Bots and pick your champ there.

About the mastery pages: you have enough time while in champ select to change them, and you can prepare them before the game as well. Just press the right button beside the shop button in the game client and go to the mastery part, you can make up to 10 mastery pages.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be **play blind pick**. Get into the champion selection screen and **pick your champion as fast as possible**. Usually this will work if you are paying attention and get in champion select as fast as you can. It is the most efficient way to play the champion you want in my opinion.

I do something similar as I've been trying to learn mid lane. So what I do is pick veigar as soon as I get in so everyone knows I'm mid and it has worked 80% of the time with the other 20% being me checking other things on the internet or someone else picking their champion as fast as me.

Answer (score -1):

As some other ppl have siad its first server, what you can do to improve your chances of getting that champion is to look where it is in your "champion list" so u can find the champion of chooise fast.